# "ovirtsdk4 version 4.4.0 or higher is required for this module" error message

Tags: python, ansible, ovirt

I am getting the error `ovirtsdk4 version 4.4.0 or higher is required for this module` when trying to use ovirt ansible roles even though the versions are satisfied.

The ovirt-engine-sdk-python is on version 4.4.6 and ansible on 2.10.1.

```sh
Requirement already satisfied: ovirt-engine-sdk-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (4.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: ansible in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (2.10.1)
```

Ansible failure:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {"discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"}, "changed": false, "msg": "ovirtsdk4 version 4.4.0 or higher is required for this module"}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you tried to install the SDK from PyPI please try to install the SDK from rpm. It's officially supported. If you have other issues please add them to
http://github.com/ovirt/ovirt-ansible-collection